# Unable to link CSS files to HTML file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link three CSS stylesheets to my **index.php** file:

- bootstrap-337.min.css
- font-awesome.min.css
- style.css

I have successfully linked bootstrap stylesheet but I am unable to link font-awesome and style stylesheet.

I had separately tested for all three and style.css is the css file I am creating for this project.

I have also tried to put css code in style tags in php file and that worked but I am unable to link css in separate stylesheet

HTML CODE:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>online store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-337.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font-awsome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

style.css:

```
/*
Template Name   : E-commerce
Author Name     : Pulkit Jain
Theme URL       : localhost/e-commerce
Theme ver       : 1.1
*/


/*General Styles*/

body {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.40;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Top Style */

#top {
    background-color: #555555;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

I am working on VS Code with Xampp Server for Ubuntu

I have tried using type attribute, '/' in the end of link tag, using '/' at the starting of the path in href:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
```

[edit: Image of the directory containing the file style.css that didn't load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbQpa.png)

[edit: Image of the directory containing the file font-awesome.css that didn't load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBBHf.png)

Comment: tell some more about your directory structure

Comment: If you open the developer console and reload the page are there any errors - specifically 404 errors referring to these CSS files?

Comment: Project is in dir where Xampp is located, i.e, /opt/lampp/htdocs/e-commerce    e-commerce contains index.php, css, js, font-awsome etc folders.

Comment: Have you tried loading them in a different order so that style is loaded last? This will ensure that bootstrap or fontawesome isn't overwriting what you have in style.

Comment: @Jason yeah initially I have tried that in first attempt.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Actually console is showing error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for jquery file and fontawesome css file

Comment: Well - that gives you somewhere to start looking. Confirm the files actually exist in the stated directories

Comment: in a comment above you state that `Project is in dir where Xampp is located, i.e, /opt/lampp/htdocs/e-commerce` and that directory contains the files that cannot be found. You try to include these files with code like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/font-awsome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`... clearly the wrong path according to earlier statement about directory structure

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius do i have to add absolute path? Also as you mentioned above about console it does show erroe about jquery file which is also not working as i had tested but online server link for jquery `"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"` is working, also apart from it only error is about font-awesome.css file, thier is no error in connection shown by console for style.css

Comment: can you add a screenshot showing the directory that contains the files that will not load - making sure that the path is visible?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i have added the images, you can check.

Comment: at the top of those images is some text that looks to be the path... is that correct?

Comment: yes that is the path. I am using ubuntu. Also I wanted to ask should I include the Xampp tag in my post as I am using xampp server, sombody edited that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the images you posted and from comments made I think you were not correctly referencing the files in whichever folders they were in - from the images I think the paths might be as follows.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/e-commerce/css/bootstrap-337.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/e-commerce/css/style.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/e-commerce/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/e-commerce/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' />
```

Comment: That worked partially, `font-awesome.min.css` started working but `style.css` is still not working.

Comment: you must confirm the paths involved. The screenshots did not clearly show the paths involved so it was a guess...what is the FULL path to those folders?

Comment: actually screenshot showed the full path clearly. For `style.css` ,  `opt\lampp\htdocs\e-commerce\css\style.css` is the absolute path

Comment: if the `font-awesome` and `styles` css files are in the same folder and the path is now correct either `styles.css` is loading and it's effects are unobserved or some other issue is preventing that file being loaded ( .htaccess perhaps or server config ??? )

Comment: `font-awsome.css` and `style.css` are in different folders, `font-awsome.css` is in `font-awsome` folder in `e-commerce` project dir, while `style.css` is in css folder in `e-commerce` dir which is same as `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: if the path used to `styles.css` is the same as the path for `bootstrap-337.min.css` ( which works?! ) then there is no reason to believe that `styles.css` is not loading unless some other factore (server config, htaccess,firewall etc ) is preventing it. Perhaps the order of loading is wrong and you cannot observe the styles in effect. How are you confirming that `styles.css` is NOT loading?

Comment: `style.css` is created by me and it is being constantly updated as project is proceeding. I am using style tags for now to see its effects and effects are clear when I use style tag.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do this:

```html
<link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'style.css'>
```

Comment: that's not correct because style is inside a folder css

Comment: @PulkitJain Oh, sorry, it's a little confusing, as the folder is called css. Have you tried it?

Comment: i have tried many things, and those are mentioned above.